# Find a string after a specific character using Jinja templates

Tags: jinja2

I'm starting off with Jinga and can't seem to figure out how to find a string after a specific character.

Here is an example:

```
{{'#' in "Test1 Test2 #Test3 Test4 #Test5 #Test6" }}
```

I was able to get as far as testing a string if it contains the "#" character. 
Now I would like to be able to somehow pull out the full words after the "#"(and before the next space) so that the resulting variable looks like this:

```
Test3 and Test5 and Test6
```

Is this possible in Jinja templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the perfect solution:

```
{% for word in "Test1 Test2 #Test3 Test4 #Test5 #Test6".split() if "#" in word %}
{{ word.replace('#', '') }}
{%- endfor %}
```